# How to Auto call an @IBAction function

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am not sure how to do auto call a click-function for an @IBAction in Swift.

Say, I have a timer function, when countdown is finished, I need to call the Click-function @IBAction as below programmatically instead of asking user to click the button

How to do it in swift?

```
@IBAction func DoSomeTask(sender: UIButton) {

- code--

}
```

Comment: Change `sender: UIButton` to `sender: UIButton!` and call `DoSomeTask(nil)` from where ever you want.

Comment: It's a function. Just call it like any other function. You will need to make the parameter `UIButton!` or `UIButton?` (optional) to be able to pass in `nil` as the sender if you don't want to pass in the button.

Comment: What is your concrete problem? It can't be calling a simple function?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can either change the signature of the IBAction by making its parameter an Optional like this:

```
@IBAction func doSomeTask(sender: UIButton?) {
    // code
}
```

and then call it with nil as an argument:

```
doSomeTask(nil)
```

Or you can use the IBAction as a wrapper for the real function:

```
func doSomeTaskForButton() {
    // ...
}

@IBAction func doSomeTask(sender: UIButton) {
    doSomeTaskForButton()
}
```

meaning you can then call `doSomeTaskForButton()` from wherever you want.

Comment: using ! or ? for these func? is there any diff using AnyObject ? : doSomeTask(sender: UIButton!) or doSomeTask(sender: AnyObject!)  or doSomeTask(sender: AnyObject?) or doSomeTask(sender: UIButton?) . It seems both condition works. Which one is the best practice?  Even user accidentally press the button again after the 1st auto Call, it still work.

Comment: `doSomeTask(sender: UIButton!)` means that you can't pass nil as an argument (the `!` force unwraps), `doSomeTask(sender: AnyObject!)` is the same but then you'll have to *cast* `sender` as an UIButton inside the IBAction to use it. `doSomeTask(sender: UIButton?)` is good because it wraps the parameter in an Optional, so you can send an actual message from button or `nil` if you don't call the IBAction from the button directly.

Answer (score 4):

`doSomeTask(UIButton())` in swift 5.0 and onward

Comment: Some context where you got `UIButton()` from might help the question asker. I know it is just part of UIKit, but I think making the action function optional, and then sending in `nil` might be the better choice for clarity, and it prevents creating a button just to fulfil the parameter of a function.

Comment: yes you are right but don't relay on optional, these two are diffrent solutions

Answer (score 1):

Do the same thing as @Moritz said but instead

```
@IBAction func doSomeTask(sender: UIButton? = nil) {
    // code
}
```

so that way, you do something like:

```
 `doSomeTask()`
```

which is saying the same thing as saying

```
 `doSomeTask(sender:nil)
```

or pass an UIButton object if you so wish so.

```
 doSomeTask(sender:SomeUIButton)
```