# UIButton isSelected by default

Tags: swift, uibutton

I need to call the IBAction method as soon as the View Controller is loaded.
I have IBOutlet for Button and IBAction. How to call IBAction by default ?

Comment: Why use a button at all? You could just call a method in ViewDidLoad. Otherwise, look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115315/how-to-auto-call-an-ibaction-function

Comment: @squarehippo10 Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // do something
}
```

Okay, what is called inside `@IBAction` is some code. Let's think about it. We can move this code somewhere else, right?

But where? Okay, it really depends on logic and architecture of your app, but for example, move it to another method.

```
func doSomething() {
    // do something
}
```

Do you see? Now we have code which was originally in action inside another method which we can call from `@IBAction`

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    doSomething()
}
```

as well as from another place from our class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A view controller doesn't really have a specific button that would have "the IBAction method". You can have 0, 1, two, or a dozen buttons in a view controller. Thus there's no general way to call "the IBAction method" for a view controller when it's first loaded.

If you have a button method:

```
@IBAction func buttonMethod(_ sender: Any?)
```

Then you can just call that method from viewDidAppear:

override dynamic public func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      buttonMethod(nil)
      //The rest of your viewDidAppear method
   }

Note that `viewDidAppear()` gets called very time the view controller is re-shown, so if you cover it with a modal and then uncover it, `viewDidAppear()` will get called again. In contrast, `viewDidLoad()` only gets called once in the lifetime of a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `IBAction` method in `viewDidLoad` by using the `IBOutlet` button as `sender`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var submtButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        submtButtonAction(submtButton)
    }
    @IBAction func submtButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    }
}
```